# regex match literal before question mark

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code:

```
        string source = @"looking for goodid\?=11 and badid\?=01 other text";
        string searchTag = @"goodid\?=[\d]*";

        while (Regex.IsMatch(source, searchTag))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found match!");
        }
```

I am trying to find the id that comes after 'goodid?' and not the one that comes after 'badid?', so the return should be 11 and not 01.

The match is not found unless i remove the text in the searchtag that precedes the question mark 'goodid'. How can I include the 'goodid' in the search alongside the question mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that in the source string `@"\?"` is interpreted as 2 characters while in the regex expression `@"\?"` will match on a single question mark. This happens because in regex `?` is a special character and needs to be escaped. If you do want to match on the two characters `@"\?"` then the regex expression will have look like this `@"goodid\\\?=[\d]*"`;

That said, there is an easier solution with named groups.

```
Match m = Regex.Match(source, @"goodid\\\?=(<id>?\d*)");

if(m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match Found: " + m.Groups["id"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved

```
Match m = Regex.Match(source, @"goodid\\\?=(?<id>\d*)");

if(m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match Found: " + m.Groups["id"].Value);
}
//changed <id>? to ?<id>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this small regex

```
(?<=goodid\\\?=)\d+
```

It uses a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that check behind the digit for `goodid\?=`

In C# it can look like

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(yourstring, @"(?<=goodid\\\?=)\d+", RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a redundant '\' in your source string, and that's the problem. If you change as:

```
string source = @"looking for goodid?=11 and badid\?=01 other text";
```

(backslash before the question mark is removed)
Then the match is found (infinite times! because it is in a while loop).